# Find source file of compiled class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, filesystems

I'm looking to find the associated source file(s) for specific class(es) in a set of compiled .net assemblies.

e.g.

```
MyAsm.Namespace.Foo  -> C:\Source\foo.cs
MyAsm.Namespace.Bar  -> C:\Source\Code\MoreCode\Common.cs
MyAsm.Namespace2.Bar -> C:\Source\Code\MoreCode\Common.cs
...
```

I have the assembly reflection / extracting the Type information I'm interested in working using standard `System.Reflection` functionality.

I now need to find the originating .cs source file for the class. While I have a brute force solution in place as a workaround, its unacceptably slow.

I would hope to have the entire process complete in ~5 seconds. Currently, the reflection extraction portion takes less than 1 second, the 'file association' takes minutes. I don't think its unreasonable to scan a couple of MB in 4 seconds.

Unfortunately there are a couple of caveats, which prevent shortcuts.

- I don't know the names of the files, so I need to do a `dir / s *.cs` every run, to enumerate all the potential source files.
- The class name won't always match the source file, it can *hint* at a possible location, but its not guaranteed to work.
- Multiple classes are defined in the same file in some cases.
- There are ~20k .cs files / 63MB of source.
- I need an association between ~10k of the classes / their files.
- I would prefer not to incrementally build a DB with the file name / classes declared in it, as the file contents will change, and I'll have the trouble of maintaining this DB etc (though I may have to go down this route if everything else fails).
- The OS's this will run on, wont have windows search/indexing enabled, so no joy there either.

**What I've tried:**

- Using findstr.exe - much too slow
- Creating a .net app, load all files into memory. - too slow to find *.cs / load all the 
  files, fast to scan the files once they are in memory.
- Creating one large source file from all the smaller files, loading it, scanning etc - again, too slow. Takes minutes to build the file, fast once loaded.
- Reading PDB files - I'm investigating PDB2XML.exe, and while it does output file names, and runs quickly, I cant see how to associate a class, with the file name.

So, does anyone have alternate suggestions, magic or some experience with PDB2XML?

Comment: What if the original source files are not present on the system?

Comment: A very simple thing to do is to do a file search for the class name, something like find all files containing `class\s+<ClassName>`

Comment: @BenFinkel they are. thats the one thing I can guarantee

Comment: @MohamedNuur Thats the 2nd item on my list of "what i've tried", and it takes too long to load all the files for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using PDBs is your best option IMHO if the files are on the disk. The file names (represented by [ISymbolDocument.URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.symbolstore.isymboldocument.url.aspx)) are related to sequence points. Sequence points are related to methods (including property get/set), not classes. Of course, a .NET class source can be stored in multiple files. So you'll have to browse all members of a type (using reflection for example) to determine all the corresponding files.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. One thing though, it not every method returns an output for `GetSequencePoints`. Autoproperties from what I can see. This makes sense, since the debugger doesn't step through them. Any way to relate them?

Comment: The compiler doesn't emit any symbol for automatic properties, as you found out, so if the class only contain these, you won't be able to determine its source file. But that should be pretty rare.

Answer (score 2):

This doesn't exactly solve the problem you are facing, as you want to get the file path of an arbitrary class but this is what easily worked for my use which is just to get a pointer to some file from the source location. I am using this in a Unit Tests so performance isn't hugely important.

```
var x = new StackTrace(true);
var file = x.GetFrame(0).GetFileName();
```

Comment: I should have said this in the question, but I need to resolve at compile time, or well after the compile, not runtime. Simon's answer was what I required.

Comment: Oh, no I didn't think this solved your particular problem very well, but I put it here since it doesn't deserve an entirely new question and I wanted the information shared.

Answer (score 2):

If you are able to edit the source. You could do it with reflection and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath. Just add the attribute into source of each file. You may need to think of something clever for partial classes.

This sample provides the source file and line number where the attribute was placed.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.All, Inherited = false, AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class SourceInfoAttribute : Attribute
{
    public SourceInfoAttribute([CallerLineNumber]int sourceLineNumber = 0, [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "")
    {
        SourceLineNumber = sourceLineNumber;
        SourceFilePath = sourceFilePath;
    }

    internal int SourceLineNumber { get; set; }
    internal string SourceFilePath { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware that there is any relationship between the file name and the assembly name in .NET, in fact there could be multiple assemblies defined in one file so I don't see how you can do this without physically viewing each source code file and searching for the class definition or maintaining a running index.