# Is there a way to know what *.cs file a given Type is coming from in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am working on a code-generator from C# to TypeScript, given an instance of .NET `System.Type` with `IsClass == true`. Is there a way to know the name of the source `*.cs` file it is coming from?

Comment: Have you looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13038249/find-source-file-of-compiled-class-in-c-sharp) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960071/how-to-find-path-to-cs-file-by-its-type-in-c-sharp)?

Comment: A debugger knows, you'd have to use the PDB file.  The DIA SDK provides the lookup feature.  Do beware the *partial* keyword.

Comment: You can get some information from PDB file, though not in all cases. Information about file is related to methods, not types, so if for example type has no methods (and no properties, because properties are just a pair of methods) - you will not be able to get source information about such type. But that is pretty rare case I guess.

Comment: The stable way of doing it is to give your code generator access to the source (to be parsed by Roslyn). Otherwise, what you've really got is a .NET to TypeScript converter, which is nice and more general than a C# converter, but you can't expect there to be any particular `.cs` file containing the class.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10960071/how-to-find-path-to-cs-file-by-its-type-in-c-sharp